# Elm JSON Decoder Array of Objects

Tags: elm

I am doing a http request with elm and my response is an Array of Objects. Each object is as follows

```
obj = {
    title: "Some Title",
    words: [ "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4" ]
}
```

Here is my decoder so far:

```
type alias ThisRes = List ResObj


type alias ResObj =
    title: String 
    words: List String


decoded : Decoder ThisRes
decoded = 
    decode ThisRes
```

I can't seem to get the decoder right and any help that can be provided would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
obj =
    """
    {
        "title": "Some Title",
        "words": [ "word1", "word2", "word3", "word4" ]
    }
    """


type alias ResObj =
    { title : String, words : List String }


objDecoder =
    map2 ResObj
        (at [ "title" ] string)
        (at [ "words" ] (list string))


headingFrom : Result String ResObj -> String
headingFrom result =
    case result of
        Ok resobj ->
            resobj.title

        Err reason ->
            toString reason


main =
    h1 [] [ text <| headingFrom <| decodeString objDecoder obj ]
```

Breaking this down:

- `obj` is just a string representing some JSON, to illustrate the example.
- You define the `ResObj` type alias, and get a type constructor for it. Now you can create `ResObj` values by calling `ResObj "MyTitle" ["word1", "wordb", "wordFightingMongooses"]`.
- `objDecoder` is a value that helps decode JSON into `ResObj`. It calls `map2`, which takes a type constructor, and then two decoded JSON fields. `(at ["title"] string)` says "turn the value at `title` in the JSON into a string" and you can guess what the next line does. So this evaluates to, ultimately, `ResObj "SomeTitle" ["word1", "word2", "word3", "word4"]` and creates your value.
- Down in our `main`, we have the expression `decodeString objDecoder obj`. `decodeString` takes a decoder value, and a JSON string, and sees if it can decode it. But it doesn't return the `ResObj` itself -- because the decoding can fail, it returns a Result.
- So we have to process that Result with our function `headingFrom`. If the decoding succeeded our result will be `Ok resobj`, and we can work with the resobj finally. If it failed it'll be `Err reason`.